# Swift - UIWebView height not fitting to iPhone screen height when loading with one page pdf

Tags: ios, swift

I have a basic webview loading some content, I have set the width and height to the main screen bounds, it works fine in iPhone 4s but for 5, 5s and so on the webivew is not fitting the entire screen height for each page of pdf. Please help. I have tried everything on stackoverflow but nothing is mentioned about the page height and device height.

```
        let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let h = bounds.size.height
        let w = bounds.size.width
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,w,h))
        webView.loadData(pdfData, MIMEType: "application/pdf", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: req)
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true
        webView.frame=self.view.bounds;
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use bounds. Get the screen's `frame height` and `frame width`. This basically lets you make the web view take up the entire view's frame.

Comment: As mentioned the problem is not with the webview, my webview is taking full screen height, but the first page in it is never taking full height ?.